# How can I determine what screen/monitor the application is running on?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007, multiscreen

On a multi-screen system, I would like some of my applications to remember which screen they were last running on and run on the same screen again.

How do I determine what the current screen/monitor is, keeping in mind that the screens may of different resolutions? The programs are written in Delphi 2007.

Comment: Don't forget that the application can be running on multiple screens. In the past I have simple captured the location and size of the application and whether it is running maximum -- on application start, simply restore the size and position. Of course, on application start you need to see if the result would be on screen so that if they are running on a screen that is no longer attached to avoid starting application off of the current desktop.

Comment: I also do exactly what Gary does. No need to remember which monitor your window is on, remember where it was.

Comment: Consider using Get/SetWindowPlacement. This takes care of such problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VCL exposes this information, for instance through the form's [`Monitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Monitor) property. This is of type [`TMonitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TMonitor) which exposes various properties of a monitor: its number, whether it is the primary monitor, its bounds and work rects and so on.

What you are trying to do though is simply to restore your form to where it was running previously. I don't think you need to remember monitor information. Simply do the following:

1. When the application closes remember its bounds rect.
2. When the application starts, set its bounds rect to the value that was remembered.
3. Check whether or not the form is contained within the screen's bounds rect. If the form is off screen then likely the user has removed a monitor or otherwise rearranged their screen. Move the form onto the nearest monitor, or the primary monitor.
4. Extra nuances needed if the window can be maximized. In that case remember bounds rect and whether or not the app is maximized. Your friends for this are `GetWindowPlacement` and `SetWindowPlacement`.

Comment: I think Get/SetWindowPlacement is the way to go because it already deals with bullet #3.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current monitor of any form using the [`Screen.MonitorFromWindow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.MonitorFromWindow) method this will return a [`TMonitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Forms.TMonitor) class with all the info which you need.

```
uses
  MultiMon;

...
...
...
var
 LMonitor : TMonitor;
 LMonitorInfo : TMonitorInfoEx;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@LMonitorInfo, SizeOf(LMonitorInfo));
  LMonitorInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(LMonitorInfo);
  LMonitor:=Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Self.Handle); //pass the handle of the form
  if not GetMonitorInfo(LMonitor.Handle, @LMonitorInfo) then
     RaiseLastOSError;
  ShowMessage(Format('The form is in the monitor Index %d - %s', [LMonitor.MonitorNum, LMonitorInfo.szDevice]));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

David was correct in that I didn't need the monitor information to do what I was trying to do.  Just for documentation.  The  **DeskTopWidth** and **DeskTopHeight** give the desktop size.

I am at home at the moment with only two screens of the same resolution.  It will be interesting to see what happens at work where I have 4 screens, 1 of which is of a different resolution.  If that doesn't work then I may have to look at the **Monitor** information too.  In case someone is wondering why the resolution is different, the 4th one is the projector.